# How can I add a pilot light to the current light switch?

Tags: electrical, pilot-light

This DIY project requires closet lights off when not in use.

How can I add a small LED indicator to show light are on or off?

Comment: There are many different ways to do this. Do you need two lights - one for on and one for off? Or just for on? Or just for off?

Comment: The make switches with a built in light indicator.  Just do an internet search for "switch with on indicator", or something similar.

Comment: If the switches are in the closet, the easiest way is to use motion sensor switches.  When the closet is unoccupied, the switch will be off. When someone enters, the switch turns the lights on.  No monitoring needed.

Answer (score 5):

If you specifically want an LED, add a suitable NRTL listed low voltage lighting supply to the circuit in parallel with the light, so it is powered when the light is, and then run your low-voltage, power-limited LED wires as you like, well separated from the line voltage wiring.

The power supply will generally either connect to a junction box, or plug in. If it plugs in, add a switched receptacle in parallel with the light and plug it in.

*Alternate solutions (which do not have an LED)* are to put the lights on:

1. a short timer, say 15 minutes maximum
2. a motion sensor
3. a refrigerator-door type switch that shuts them off when the door
   closes, and turns them on when it opens.

Answer (score 4):

This might be too far outside the box, but get a clear nylon rod, drill a friction fit hole through the top of the closet door and stick the 1-3/8" long rod into the hole. Voila! An indicator light.

Comment: Nylon? PMMA (acrylic) or polycarbonate (Lexan) makes a much better clear optical pathway. Nylon isn't particularly clear, more of a translucent white or yellow-white at best. But with a clear rod, or large diameter optical fiber, yup, that'll work.

Comment: Ohh. Forgot this one, and it's SPIFFY for this task. Plastic scintillating fibers. They are neat, have fancy scientific uses, but are commonly available as archery sights. You'd take a couple of loops around the light, and then drill a hole in the wall, and you get a bright colored (you pick when buying) spot, brightness variable with how much fiber (on the side, not the end) you've exposed to the light. Looks very like an LED.

Answer (score 3):

There are lighted switches which have a small (neon?) light in the toggle. The light is on when the switch is off. I believe the purpose of this is to reveal the switch in darkness, but this could be used as an indicator of the state of a light in a closet.

https://a.co/d/0Fbo7QE

Comment: All the big box home improvement chains I've ever seen stock multiple varieties of lighted switches. They even make fancy ["decora"-style ones](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Leviton-15-Amp-120-Volt-277-Volt-Decora-LED-Illuminated-Rocker-Single-Pole-AC-Quiet-Switch-Residential-Grade-Grounding-White-R02-L5611-2LW/315717567).

Comment: Doesn't help if the switch is inside the closet.

Answer (score 1):

Install a "door activated light switch" in the jamb. When the door closes, the light will turn on, when it's open the light will turn off.

"Wait," I hear you say, "I want the light to be *off* when the door is *closed*."

Wire it backwards.

Comment: Wire it "backwards"?  The door activated switches that I have seen in operation turn on the light when the door is open and turn off the light when the door is closed.